# How can i keep my Diagrams Updated with ant jobs ?

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, spring, ant, uml

My team works on a (Spring/Java/JSP-Intellij + Mysql + Flex/Cairgornm/BlazeDS) Monster that we all love, we need to keep the diagrams updated, specifically class diagram for the Java and Flex layers, and the mysql database diagram model, so new interns can understand faster the arqhitecture and be productive with less effort.

The thing is we are always developing and branching and merging and having release dates and mutating everything (all the builds are ant tasks).

What i would love is a solution were ant would be able to generate all the diagrams based on source code, like the Javadoc Tasks.

Is this posible for us ?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you generate them now? There are Javadoc doclets that include ER diagrams. There are tools to create diagrams from databases. What have you found when searching, and what was wrong with them?

Answer (score 1):

[Schemaspy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) produces nice [diagrams](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/relationships.html) and other also other information about database schema. You can run it from the ant, there is no specific ant task, but it is just jar. Some instruction can be found from [here](http://jbrugge.com/blog/2006/10/18/schemaspy-to-the-rescue/).

[Apiviz](http://code.google.com/p/apiviz/) generates kind of UML diagrams. It can be from ant, spefically as a [javadoc](http://code.google.com/p/apiviz/#Ant_Integration) task.